# How to build a search engine in windows form that searches for folders in C drive using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, search-engine, windows-forms-designer

I'm making a documentation program and I built a search engine with text boxes,combo boxes,and check list boxes. I haven't written a code that actually does the searching, there are just buttons and the components.

Anyways the files I want to access are in one folder in the C drive and in that folder there are many other folders and subfolders. I want the user to either type in the desired name of the folder,or select from a combo box.Normally we can open a folder with this code:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Users\melek\Desktop\svn");
```

I don't want to write Users\melek etc each time in code. I need a code that grabs the users selected folder or file name(using combo boxes and text boxes) and find the folder and display it in windows form.

Is it possible to convert the selection from the text box or combo box to string and use the Process.Start command?

**We solved this problem like this: 
we obtained a path and used this code:
listBox1.DataSource = System.IO.Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(path1);**

Comment: Yes, it is possible. As it stands, it's unclear what you're asking and impossible to provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: Can someone explain how in detail ?

Comment: [Start by reading up on how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question accordingly and you'll see good answers popping up.

Comment: The problem is that this looks like a very simple task, your title is misleading, your description is vague and you seem to be asking someone to write your code for you. Clearly you are a newbie and have much to learn, but you really will have to focus on asking a better question rather than complaining about not getting instant answers. What _exactly_ is it that you don't know how to do?

Comment: complex? google "list files in directory c#". 3.5 million results. And yeah, i may come off rude but the amount of beginner level questions on SO is just crazy now.

Comment: Yeah it does look like a simple task but we're struggling (my team and I) and we're newbies in c#.Im asking for a small code sample...not someone to code the whole thing.I cant find a better way to ask this question so...This program is more complex than it looks and maybe for some people it may seem extremely easy but right now for us its kind of difficult.

Comment: If i hadnt checked google I wouldnt be asking here now would I.

Comment: @melek_3 This site is not about experts helping newbies who apparently didn't bother with the very basic functions of core library classes. If it's taking you and your "team" multiple days to figure out how to obtain a directory list from a given path there's something seriously wrong. This site is for people who actually do this as a serious job and ran out of ideas with something and are looking for new input.

Comment: I had a question and I asked...it takes courage because its people like you who are afraid to ask.Just because I'm a newbie doesnt mean you have to look down upon me and make it seem that my question is incredibly stupid.I googled,I asked my other friends who study computer engineering just like me and my last resort was here.

Comment: If i hadnt actually tried to search for myself and actually TRY then I wouldnt be arguing with you but because I've been trying my best (considering that im very new to C#) your argument is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do requires several steps, so let's discuss them in turn.

First you need to get a path from the user so your program knows where to search . A [FolderBrowserDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog(v=vs.110).aspx) attached to a button provides this. No need to hard code any paths since you can fetch the path string from this dialog.

Next you can use the [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx), [Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory(v=vs.110).aspx) and [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx) classes to perform operations such as, fetching a list of all subfolders from a path, extracting paths of paths as strings for additional searching, and checking properties or flags on files and folders in case you decide to support more advanced search options.

I would suggest understanding these core file system classes more if you're going to be doing any amount of development that interacts with the file system. They are your bread and butter. I've linked to the MSDN documentation for each, for your convenience.